# Is there any serious romance in No Game No Life?

Tags: no-game-no-life

I know the genre of this anime, however after watching "Your lie in April" and "Plastic Memories" in a row, I feel I need to tread very very lightly before watching a new anime, as they had a significant emotional impact on me.

So, is it romantic is there a serious romantic theme. Or is it more aimed at funny and/or sarcastic relations (lighthearted romance), such as in D-frag or Prison-school?

If possible I would like to avoid the more serious romantic/drama series for now.

Comment: I guess what you really want to ask is whether *No Game No Life* is a romance-*tragedy*? Or are you trying to avoid any romance anime even if it's cheerful? (Just asking for clarification since I don't watch all)

Comment: Why do i have a feeling like you are asking for the recommendation. which is off topic. but the way you are asking the question is off or not, i don't know.

Comment: no game no life anime does not have that romantic part as the anime you mentioned in your description and does not fall under romance genre

Comment: @AkiTanaka yes you're right.. I'm asking whether it's romance-tragedy or not.. however I'm not a fan of romance anyways

Comment: Welcome to A&M, I rephrased your question a bit, to make the question and the emphasis a bit clearer, if you feel that some meaning was lost, feel free to revert, or edit it back into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, No game no life is not 'romantic' in the way plastic memories and your lie in April where, the emotional touching way.

No game no life focuses a lot more on a 'comedic aspect' of romanticism, and over the top brother sister love. And all though this is a red line throughout the series, the games they play have the bigger focus in the 'serious' parts of the series.

Answer (score 0):

The anime kinda glosses over it, but the light novels have a very light running romance. Steph sincerely feels something for Sora beyond the feelings that she is coerced to feel. There shouldn't be any problem watching the anime, since not only is the romance less pronounced, it doesn't gain any significant developments since the anime is only 3 light novels of source material